# Unit testing randomly stops working in Visual Studio . Has anyone else had this problem, and if so how do I fix it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

My unit tests in Visual studio almost never run saying 'Test not run'. This happens regardless of the project. All day Yesterday they ran and passed with the only issue being a test in a test class I deleted still passed for some reason. I didn't do anything different yesterday, I just open Visual Studio as normal. I closed my laptop lid last night and attempted to run them again this morning and now they will not run again. Has anyone had this issue before? I have Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Yes, I've had this problem. Not found a solution, though it seems to occur if I have multiple test projects using different test libraries. Usually it goes away with a Visual Studio restart.

Comment: I've restarted my entire computer and had no luck. I also only have 1 test project and 1 test class.

Comment: See if removing the `.vs` folder and all `obj` folders before restarting Visual Studio and cleaning does the trick. Most times that’ll work for me

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem was that my desktop folder that contained my project was in my One Drive. I moved it to my C drive and now the tests run again.

Answer (score 0):

I found this which used to cure a similar problem in VS2017:

1) Close Visual Studio
2) In Windows Explorer, find c:\users[Your Account]\AppData\Local\Temp
3) Delete everything in the folder
4) Empty the recycle bin

I'm not convinced of the need for (4) and the exact location of (2) may vary depending on your setup.

Comment: No luck still after doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue; moving the code to my C drive and clearing AppData\Local\Temp didn't help. Turns out that in one function, I accidentally called itself instead of the intended function, causing infinite recursion that led to a StackOverflowException.

If you have this issue, try **identifying a test that stops and run in debug mode** since running the test normally didn't catch the StackOverflow, but debug mode did.